# REST DELETE Call To External System Returns Status Code 0

Tags: apex, callout

I have a REST API call that I'm trying to make using a DELETE method. However, the request is returning a status code of 0 with nothing in the response body. If I take my endpoint and run the request in Postman it works perfectly. Any ideas what's wrong?

Here is the example code:

```
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/' + PageId + '/subscribers/' + SubscriberId);
        request.setMethod('DELETE');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + APIKey);  
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the send request code in:

```
response = http.send(request)
```

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the info.

Comment: If the code in the question is what was present, then this is indeed an answer.